# Cannot hide view after animation

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I am creating an animation which brings an image and a label from the left to the centre of the view.

1. `imageLogo.isHidden = true` is not hidden when App is run
2. `labelLogo` is not shown at all on the view

I have been reading tutorials, but I just don't see what is wrong with my code.

```
let paymentLogo = UIImage(named: "paymentImage")
var imageLogo:UIImageView!
var overlayView = UIView()
var logoAppeared:Bool!
let labelLogo = UILabel()

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //move picture off the screen here

    self.imageLogo = UIImageView(image:paymentLogo)
    imageLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    imageLogo.center.x -= 400
    self.view.addSubview(imageLogo)

    self.labelLogo.frame =
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    self.labelLogo.center.x -= 400
    self.labelLogo.text = "Booking Completed"
    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
    self.view.addSubview(labelLogo)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.1, options: [], animations: {
        //animate paymentCompletedLogo
        self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4

        //animate labelLogo
        self.labelLogo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: 90, width: 200, height: 21)
        self.labelLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.labelLogo.text = "Booking Completed"
        self.labelLogo.textColor = .black
        self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center

        //animate imageLogo
        self.imageLogo.frame =
            CGRect(x: self.view.center.x,y: self.view.center.y,width: 100,height: 100)

        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)
        self.view.addSubview(self.imageLogo)
        self.view.addSubview(self.labelLogo)
    }) { finished in
        self.overlayView.isHidden =  true
        self.imageLogo.isHidden = true //it is not hidden in simulator

        self.logoAppeared = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried removing following your code from animation method it worked fine.
You are trying to add subview in animation method. imageLogo and labelLogo is all ready added in view.

```
   self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)
   self.view.addSubview(self.imageLogo)
   self.view.addSubview(self.labelLogo)
```